# Sql query where column value is unique and don't include

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table called **users** with columns

Logins
 first name
 last name
 and email addresses.

What I want to be appeared is 
**Email** which is not **unique** and don’t show email addresses which starts from “**geen**” and “**na**”.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: sql-server or mysql?

Comment: yes sql-server, because I'm using sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `like` to remove emails that start or contain certain strings in the `where` clause.

If you just want the `email` column and the number of duplicates you can use `count()` aggregation with `group by` and use `having` clause to only show results with a `count(*) > 1`:

```
select email, count(*) as cnt
from users
where email not like 'green%'
  and email not like 'na%'
group by email
having count(*) > 1
```

---

If you want to see all of the row data for those emails that have duplicates you could use a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) along with the `count(*) over()` window aggregation function or [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;with cte as  (
  select *
    , row_number() over (partition by email order by lastname, firstname) as rn
    , count(*) over (partition by email) as cnt
  from users
  where email not like 'green%'
    and email not like 'na%'
)
select *
from cte
where cnt > 1
  --or email like '%[0123456789]'  /* uncomment to also show emails ending in a number */
order by email, rn
```

Comment: thank you very much @SqlZim. It is working. 
My real issue that in the db there is some data discrepancies.
What I want is to remove email addresses which starts from "geen" or "na" and ends with some digits. Because there are some users who put their email addresses like slsl@slsl.com123 and I want them as well to be listed so I can modify them

Comment: @user2983359 You could include `or email like '%[0123456789]'` to show emails that end in a number, in addition to duplicates, in the second query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) AS qty
FROM users
WHERE email NOT LIKE 'geen%'
AND email NOT LIKE 'na%'
GROUP BY email
HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1 )
```

Comment: Hi @SqlZim, sorry didn't notice you already answered. I upvoted yours :)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM USERS
WHERE EMAIL NOT LIKE 'geen%'
    AND EMAIL NOT LIKE 'na%'